# Adding round argument in options

Tags: r

I am facing a problem in my code where i am multiplying two numbers and not getting the exact answer

```
> x<-0.1
> y<-6
> x*y==0.6
[1] FALSE
> x*y-0.6
[1] 0.0000000000000001110223025
```

Is there a way to add round in the options for 15 digits and not adding the function round to each one of my calculations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to do this with floating point arithmetic is to avoid the strict equality operator `==`. You can use `near` from `dplyr` for example:

```r
x <- 0.1
y <- 6
x * y == 0.6
#> [1] FALSE
dplyr::near(x * y, 0.6)
#> [1] TRUE
```

or define your own function that does the same thing:

```
eq <- function(a, b) abs(a - b) < 1e-6
eq(x * y, 0.6)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my case is bit different: ```                                                              > vec<-c(0.3,0.4,0.6)
> 
> x<-0.1 ; y<-6;
> which(vec<x*y)
[1] 1 2 3```

Comment: i can implement your function also here, i thought there there was something simpler where i wont change all of the functions (== , < , >) with the new ones

Comment: @Basel.D I answered the question in the format you asked it. If you  need something different please edit your question to make it clear, rather than using comments for amendments.